# Выездное меню с помощью перетаскивания указателя (мыши)

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

Подскажите, стоит выездное меню с левой стороны, как сделать чтобы его можно было открыть проведя мышью (или пальцем, если с телефона) слева-направо (как в мобильных  приложениях)?

Comment: покажите код....

Comment: @Избытоксусликов та если можно пример по div, там дальше разберусь

Answer (score 3):

На **jQuery**

```js
$(function(){
 $('.slider-arrow').mouseover(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=300"
    }, 700, function() {
          });
  $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {    
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=300"
    }, 700, function() {
          });
  $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');   
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.panel {
 width:300px;
 float:left;
 height:550px;
 background:#d9dada;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;

}
.slider-arrow {
 padding:5px;
 width:10px;
 float:left;
 background:#d9dada;
 font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

На **CSS**

```css
#mySidenav a {
    position: absolute;
    left: -80px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
    left: 0;
}
#about {
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: тут при наведении мышью меню выезжает, а нужно чтобы по клику. зажимаешь клик мыши и проводишь слева-направо

Comment: в вопросе такого не было что __зажимаешь клик мыши и проводишь слева-направо__